# Communication between Spring Mvc controller and javascript : is it possible?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc

I'm developing a web application with `spring Mvc` and my views are designed with  `bootstrap` 
I have to display some data from the database in a Linear Chart (a dashboard) in my views.

I found [this snippet](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/ZkOAl) and that's what I want to put in my views

But the problem is that the data of the example is set by `Javascript` .I'm new with `Spring Mvc` I don't know if  I can send data from my controller to javascript or I can't ?

Any help is really apreciated.

Comment: You can call your spring controller methods using ajax and then process the results in javascript. Take a look at this http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-4-mvc-ajax-hello-world-example/

Comment: thanks a lot for the link +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easy : with Spring you can easily expose your data as json in order to be able to communicate with Javascript World.

Check Jackson (https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson). It's a framework that handle the json serialization for you, the sample provided will show you how to setup a controller than handle JSON.

Note Jackson comme with a tons of functionnality and module like :

1. cycle detection
2. Hibernate entities/proxies handling (jackson-datatye-hibernate)
3. ...